# The best way to protect model->load() from saving wrong inputs

Tags: php, security, model, yii2

In yii2 app I have `User` model. For example, I have fields `name` and `is_admin` (0 or 1).
When user signs up, he enters `name` only.

He has `user/update` page to edit his `name`. But, if you are admin, you can also edit everyones page and set `is_admin` field also (for admins it is visible on page).

Rules are like:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['name', 'string'],
        ['is_admin', 'integer'],
    ];
}
```

**Q**: How to protect action from ability users to set them admins from `user/update` page by putting another `<input name="User[...]">`?

That means everyone can replace input attribute `name="User[name]"` to `name="User[is_admin]"` and set value to `1`. Then `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` automatics sets `is_admin` var.

Yes, I can by hand empty `is_admin` in `$_POST`, but in real project I have 20+ fields in db table and a lot of actions, it is hard everytime to check what inputs I have in every view and compare.

Controller:

```
$model = User::findIdentity($id);

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    if ($model->save())
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scenario`. for example:

in your `model`

```php
const SCENARIO_USER_SAVE = 'user-save'; // anything you want to call your scenario
public function scenarios()
{
    return [            
        self::SCENARIO_USER_SAVE => ["field1","field2"], // list only the fields you will allow user to update
    ];
}
```

now in your `controller` use the scenario

```php
$model = User::findIdentity($id);
$model->scenario = User::SCENARIO_USER_SAVE; // use the scenario

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    if ($model->save())
        ...
}
```

**note** that the fields which are not allowed in the scenario will have **`NULL`** value when you do
`$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` no matter what you send via form

**Updated:** other fields which are not allowed in the scenario will NOT be updated/saved when calling `$model->save()` *(i have tested it)*

Detail guide here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios

Comment: "fields which are not allowed in the scenario will have NULL value" - that means if user can not set `is_admin`, this field `is_admin` will be set to `NULL`?

Comment: yes. and in my knowledge it will not be updated, it will remain same as before.

Comment: thank you for reply. Do you know can I set in scenario list of fields that you can NOT update (instead of list that you can update)?

Comment: i think its possible. i haven't done it myself, so can't tell you exactly how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ActiveRecord` `beforeValidate` in that case, something like that:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord
{

    public function beforeValidate(){
        //If User Role  is Not Admin $user is User ActiveRecord Object
        if($user->role === 'user'){
            $this->is_admin = 0;
        }
     parent::beforeValidate();
     }
}
```